# latex minipage positioning

Tags: latex

Latex documentation reads that minipage can be positioned via formula in [ ] brackets.
I tried

```
 \begin{minipage}[posx=0,posy=0]{2cm} TO1 \end{minipage} 
 \begin{minipage}[posx=0,posy=2]{2cm} TO1 \end{minipage}
```

posx and posy seems not to be proper formula.
How to do this?
How to put minipage in arbitrary place?

Comment: Where in which documentation did you find this?

Comment: The syntax of minipage is `\begin{minipage}[position][height][inner-pos]{width}
content...
\end{minipage}`. I you want more arbitrary positioning than this syntax offers, have a look at the `picture` environment or, getting the heavy weapons out, tikz.

Comment: BUT what would be complete code sample? because what I gave above is not working

Comment: @josh.bauer2020 for example `\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][c]{2cm} content... \end{minipage}` For the position you can use `T,t,c,b` and for inner pos `t,c,b`

Comment: I see. It allows me only top,center,bottom. What about picture environment. Can I be able to position picture in exact position on page?

Comment: Thanks. I got it finally with picture environment.